# Find hash keys across multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `variables` field in my table that stores miscellaneous data in a hash.

What I need to do is iterate over all the rows in find the keys that are in use.

For instance, here are 3 examples of what the `variables` field could hold...

```
Row 1: {:email=>"bob@example.com", :user_id=>"13", :last_seen=>"January 14, 2013"}
Row 2: {:user_id=>"13", :last_seen=>"January 14, 2013", :favorite_color=>"red"}
Row 3: {:order_count=>87}
```

So, the keys I want are: `email, user_id, last_seen, favorite_color, order_count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a good way to store data, as you can see. You can't take advantage of indexes, and EVERY query has to do in-string searches, which are terribly inefficient. Instead, break your table in to the fields you need, or create a table that is for variable storage. I'd use something like this as a schema for a table I'd call `user_vars`:

```
id integer
user_id integer
var_name string
var_value string
```

Using the `user_id` you can find all variables associated with a particular user. From the result of a search like:

```
select var_name, var_value from user_vars where user_id = 1;
```

you'd get all variables for that user.

Using:

```
select var_name, var_value from user_vars where user_id = 1 and var_name in ('email', 'user_id', 'last_seen', 'favorite_color', 'order_count');
```

you'd get just the records you want for a particular user.

Indexing could be set up for all fields, so your database could find things extremely fast.

Active Record would make this a trivial search.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
all_keys = variables.map{ |hash| hash.keys }.flatten
```

The shorter version:

```
all_keys = variables.map(&:keys).flatten
```

you may need to add a `uniq` as your wishes

The backtrace in my IRB console (1.9.3):

```
a = [ {a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 4, a: 3} ]
#=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:c=>4, :a=>3}]
a.map(&:keys).flatten
#=> [:a, :b, :c, :a]
```

Comment: Where are you getting `@variables` from?

Comment: Right, across thousands of rows. How are you combining the values from the `variables` field from multiple rows?

Comment: This would be significantly more efficient if you stored these attributes in a key/value association table. Serialized data is very expensive to manipulate like this since thousands of records must be loaded and de-serialized, potentially using up several GB of memory if you're not careful.

Comment: Arf, there is no "proper" way to select which value you want (for exemple with the key `:last_seen`, its difficult to determine which value to keep if you apply a `uniq`) (you would need to create your own aggregate function to determine which value to keep)

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) is a good method to go with this kind of case.

```
ar = [
    {:email=>"bob@example.com", :user_id=>"13", :last_seen=>"January 14, 2013"},
    {:user_id=>"13", :last_seen=>"January 14, 2013", :favorite_color=>"red"},
    {:order_count=>87}
]

ar.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
# => [:email, :user_id, :last_seen, :favorite_color, :order_count]
```